# Difficulty installing MonoGame extension in Visual Studio 2022 (Install Failed error)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, monogame

I'm encountering difficulties while trying to install the MonoGame extension in Visual Studio 2022. I followed the standard installation process, but it consistently fails with an "Install Failed" error. I've tried various troubleshooting steps, but none have resolved the issue. I'm seeking guidance on how to successfully install the MonoGame extension in Visual Studio 2022.

Any assistance or suggestions on resolving this installation issue would be greatly appreciated.

I may have overlooked something but I asked IT technicians on my school about it but still the error or the MonoGame extension don't appear in the extensions/manage extensions tab

Specifically, I've ensured compatibility, ran Visual Studio as an administrator, disabled antivirus software, cleared the Visual Studio cache, and attempted to repair the Visual Studio installation. Despite these efforts, the installation still fails with the same error.

Comment: Are you following the process shown in the [official docs](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_windows.html) ? I think you are following instructions related to the older versions.

Comment: I uninstalled my templates, and reinstalled it and I can assure you it works. Can you please specify where exactly are you getting "Installed Falied" error message?